# Django - Form - ForeignKey - Hidden - Default value

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, hidden-field

I have a Hidden ForeignKey in an update form that I want to set to value of default value of 2 in my html form, but I can't get it to work.

forms.py

```
    eval_sent_state = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=2,queryset=models.EvalUrlSentState.objects.all())
```

The Html output i get:

```
<input type="hidden" name="eval_sent_state" value="1" id="id_eval_sent_state">
```

from views.py

```
class ClassSchoolTeacherUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.ClassSchool
    form_class = forms.ClassSchoolTeacherForm
    pk_url_kwarg = "pk"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return models.ClassSchool.objects.get(class_random_key=self.kwargs.get("random"))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['username'] = self.kwargs.get('username')
        context['random'] = self.kwargs.get('random')
        return context
```

from models.py:

```
class ClassSchool(models.Model):

    # Relationships
    eval_sent_state = models.ForeignKey("EvalUrlSentState", default=1,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    # Fields
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_student_size = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class_subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_element_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_teacher_user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    eval_year = models.IntegerField(default=2022)
    class_random_key = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    eval_url = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    eval_open_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: Can you show your view? If this is an update view then the field will take the value from the existing instance being updated

Comment: Anyway to change a default value in an update view?

Comment: Do you want your view to always set that field to a certain value? Overriding the form_valid method on the view or the save method on the form is probably the way to go

Comment: In this form and veiew I always want it to save this value to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your form to always set the `eval_sent_state` field to the value you want in the `save` method, you should remove the field from the form fields though

```
class ClassSchoolTeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ClassSchool
        exclude = ['eval_sent_state']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.eval_sent_state_id = 2
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```